# What is the history of the Australian slang word "sleeps" (meaning days)?

Tags: etymology, slang, australian-english

What is the history of the Australian slang word "sleeps" to mean 'days'?

I lived in Sydney many years ago and the term was not used then.  For the past three years or so I've increasingly heard "sleeps" used as a reference for the number of days away something is in communications from Australian entities, e.g., a radio station DJ saying that a concert or such will be in "four sleeps," or email from a film festival that it starts in "only six more sleeps." I'd not come across the term used in this way before, so I was curious.

Comment: This is also used in the UK, but only around kids and normally looking to the future - something like "5 sleeps until christmas". How does this compare to the use you know?

Comment: '**Sleeps** "Just two more sleeps until my birthday,” Timmy says as you tuck the covers in tight. There’d be no problem were Timmy a freckly youngster in cartoon pyjamas. Timmy, however, is a middle manager in his 30s and, predictably, his birthday is set to last a whole week, because these things always do. But this isn’t just infantilisation, according to David Crystal, it’s a very old English usage, proving that basicness is one genetic trait we can’t breed out.' (Guardian, https://www.theguardian.com/science/2017/jan/20/totes-annoying-words-should-be-banned)

Comment: **Irish** slang, I suspect.

Comment: Meaning not *days,* but ***nights***, rather: "A three days and two sleeps camp."

Comment: *OED* attests 'sleep' in the sense of "an indication or division of time" as early as Old English (1131 in the *Anglo-Saxon Chronicles*). After that (from about 1670), the sense was commonly used when imitating aboriginal (esp. American Indian) conceptualizations. Is that what you had in mind, or can you be more precise about the context leading you to believe it is Australian slang?

Comment: I can recall seeing "sleeps", in this sense, used in the US, in what I'm remembering was children's literature from roughly 1920 to 1950.  Have not seen it for a couple of decades, though, and I suppose it may have been "borrowed" from Australian lingo.

Comment: This will be quite useful in The Future, when we all live on space stations.

Comment: You can guess why Wyoming's _Ten Sleep Canyon_ was so named in the days before decent roads and cars.